# Node.js - Why checkAuthenticated middleware function cannot be exported from another file?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a node.js app that uses express, handlebars and passport.js for authentication. I have setup a routes folder for login

app.js

```
app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));
```

routes/ login.js

```
const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect("/");
    }

    next();
};

router.get("/", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});

module.exports = router;
```

This works fine.

However, if I put the checkAuthenticated middleware function in app.js then export and require it in login.js I get this error.

> router.get() requires callback

app.js

```
app.use('/login', require('./routes/login.js'));

const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect("/");
}

next();
};

module.exports = { checkAuthenticated };
```

routes/login.js

```
const { checkAuthenticated } = require('../app.js');

router.get("/", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
res.render("login");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Why doesn't it work when this function is required from another file like a normal function? I am trying to avoid duplication as I need exact same function for routes/register.js

Comment: bcoz that would create a circular dependency

Comment: You'll have to show exactly how you export and import it.  Perhaps you aren't doing that correctly or perhaps you have created a circular dependency which means you need to move some shared code that both files need to a third file and import it from there.

Comment: Also, in your middleware you need to `return` after calling `res.redirect()` so you don't call `res.redirect()` AND then call `next()`.  One or the other, not both.

Comment: Abhishek - I'm not sure how it would create a circular dependency as it is referencing the function from another file? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: jfriend00 - regarding your second comment - I made a mistake when copying the code over, the return was inside the if statement.

Comment: circular bcoz you would be importing `checkAutheticated` from `app.js` while in `app.js` you're already importing the `login.js`